# Define the bilinear form L on R2 by L(x,y) = det [x,y] and find its matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

"Define the bilinear form L on R2 by L(x,y) = det[x,y],i.e. to compute L(x,y) we form a 2×2 matrix with columns x,y and compute its determinant. Find the matrix of L."

I'm still not clear on what a bilinear form is, but based on what I've read I need to find a matrix A where $x^{T}Ay$ is equal to the determinant of x,y. Since det[x,y] is $x_{1}y_{2}-y_{1}x_{2}$ the matrix should be

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    -1 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bilinear forms are generalization of the scalar product of vectors: let $V$ be a real vector space, a function $b:V\times V\to\Bbb R$ (assigning a real number to each pair of vectors) is a bilinear form, if it is linear in both variables when the other variable is fixed on any value, that is, if it satisfies the following distribution-like properties:
$$b(u+\lambda v,\,w)=b(u,w)+\lambda\,b(v,w)\\
b(u,\,v+\lambda w)=b(u,v)+\lambda\,b(u,w)\,.$$
The determinant on $\Bbb R^2$ is a bilinear form. (In an $n$ dimensional space, it would be *multilinear* on $n$ arguments.)

Using bilinearity of $b$, one can see that it's uniquely determined by its values taken on pairs of basis elements for any fixed basis, and more specifically, as you write, letting $B:=(b(e_i,e_j))_{i,j}$ we obtain
$$b(v,w)=[v]^TB[w]$$
where $[v]$ is the column vector of coordinates of vector $v$ in basis $(e_i)_i$.